# StimulSoft 'Unsupported Media Type' when login web api

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, report, stimulsoft

I want to create report in stimulsoft and using web api to get data. For this purpose i select OData connection in stimulsoft.
But after enter `login` url and `Username` and `password` get 'Unsupported Media Type'

[image]

But when i test url and username and password in postman every thing are good. How can i get data from `web api` in stimulsoft ?

Comment: You need to share your WebApi controller code - or some sample to get a clear answer